# How can I align an element (h3) at the bottom of a div?

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have two headers (h2 and h3) inside a div, and I want to align the second (h3) to the bottom of the div right above the bottom-border. I'm working with some inherited code, and the height is responsive, so can't be set. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/peakera/pen/abWYWVx). Here's the HTML:

```
 <div id="toc-texts">
  <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 1 That is Actually Really Long</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 1</h3>    
  </div>
   <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 2</h3>    
  </div>
   <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 3</h3>    
  </div>
 </div>
```

And here's the css I have so far:

```
div#toc-texts {
    display: inline;
  } 

div.toc-entry {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  div#toc-texts {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 9rem 9rem 9rem;
    grid-gap: 4em;
  }
  
}
```

How can I align the h3 to the bottom of the div in a way that works on all browsers and on mobile?

Comment: [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) will come in handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flexbox column.

Push the `h3` to the bottom with `margin-top:auto` and then align right.

```css
div#toc-texts {
  display: inline;
}

div.toc-entry {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h3.author {
  font-size: .9em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  div#toc-texts {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 9rem 9rem 9rem;
    grid-gap: 4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="toc-texts">
  <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 1 That is Actually Really Long</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="toc-entry">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Author Name 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```